# Distributing the Master Public Key in Identity-based Encryption systems

Tags: encryption, elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, pki, identity-based-encryption

I was just wondering how the private key generator should publish the master public key inside of an IBE system. This key is needed for all devices in the network to derive the public key of receiving entities.

Answer (score 1):

The master public key is public, so it can be distributed like any other message. The key generator can send it to all devices using a one-to-one protocol like CoAP or a pub/sub protocol like MQTT.

Since all devices in the system need to know it, the pub/sub protocol may be more efficient depending on the number of devices. The actual protocol choice will depend on your system.

Whatever the case, publishing the master public key is not a matter of cryptography but of information exchange. Apply the usual security principles for any message exchange, and you should be fine.